# Erlang for Rabbitmq

Tags: apt, rabbitmq, erlang

Trying to install Rabbitmq to AWS Ubuntu 18.04. First I need to install Erlang:

```
wget -O- https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/erlang_solutions.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu bionic contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install erlang
```

Erlang version 22 installed.

Now installing Rabbitmq:

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list
```

This brought line below to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list`: `deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic main`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install rabbitmq-server
```

This brings error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-nox (>= 1:13.b.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            esl-erlang but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is wrong with Erlang? According description Erlang 22 should support Rabbitmq 3.8.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See this gist for a series of commands to install Erlang and RabbitMQ on Ubuntu:

https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/bd90852537928b4f8801bae9aa051bf0

Change `xenial` to your version.

---

<sub>**NOTE:** the RabbitMQ team monitors the `rabbitmq-users` [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.</sub>